# Bootstrap make only several elements inline

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I need to place text input fields inline and put textarea in a new line with full size.

Can I make it with default Bootstrap styles?

```html
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject">
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="message"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
<textarea class="message"></textarea>
```

With:

```
<textarea class="form-control message"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get this done without writing any additional CSS code.

**HTML Markup**

```
<form class="row" role="from">
  <div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
    <textarea class="form-control" class="message" rows="5"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/ElmahdiMahmoud/details/raXgyj/)

Hope this helps.